# phpmyadmin not connecting using docker---- Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Tags: wordpress, macos, docker, phpmyadmin

I'm a newbie when it comes to Docker. For my setup I'm installing Docker for the purpose of running a MySQL WordPress on a MacOS environment.

Below is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8080:80
wordpress_db:
  image: mariadb
phpmyadmin:
  image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8181:80
mysql:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress_db
    - MYSQL_USER=sbroot
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
```

Is `docker-compose up -d to terminal` the correct approach? Also, are there any alternatives to using Docker to achieve the same result?

Comment: Nothing forces you to use Docker, and you might find it educational to start up the pieces separately not in Docker.  The Docker Compose YAML file you show has one long-outdated feature (you shouldn't use `links:` on current setups) and is missing a key piece of configuration (both services that consume the MySQL database need its magic Docker host name, probably `mysql` and login credentials).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you add it or not, but you have to put the following lines on top of your docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
```

What I can see in your file, two database images, 1) mysql and 2) mariaDb. You should keep only one of those for e.g. mysql for instance.

And what error do you get, when you visit link, http://localhost:8081 ?